# Render Email AMPScript without sending

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have a solution to add the content of the email into a Data Extension. There is a content area on every script that runs on every send and Inserts content in a data extension specific to the subscriber.

It works fine, however I would like to know If it is possible to send the email to a list of Subscriber´s in a data extension but without sending it, only rendering the email and executing the AMPscript to insert the content into a Data Extension as many times as subscriber´s are in the sending data extension.

Not sure If a Audience Exclusion will work here...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, but there's a business rule that you can have enabled in your account to provide a "send all all emails to" option in the Guided Send wizard.  The emails still get sent, just to a single email address.

You could send to a SFMC black-hole email address if you wanted:

`test-whatever@bh.exacttarget.com`

It looks like this:

[image: send all emails]

Comment: Hi Adam, do you know If there will be a problem on that email not being sent at all because the email address used: test-whatever@bh.exacttarget.com is somehow blacklisted then the email not rendered at all?

Just need to propose a solution that will always work.
Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest trying it out.